# Loan Calculator (jQuery) not working right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loan calculator that I have built using JQuery, HTML, and CSS. It functions ok. The weird thing is I have to refresh the page in order to get it to calculate correctly. I'm not sure what I'm doing (or not doing) correctly. Would love some feedback.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // variables
  var amount = $('#loanAmount').val();
  var yearlyInterestRate = .12;
  var monthlyInterestRate = yearlyInterestRate / 12;
  var twelveMon = 12;
  var eighteenMon = 18;
  var twentyFourMon = 24;
  var duration = $('input[name=duration]:checked').val();
  var calcButton = $('.calculate');
  var resetButton = $('.reset');
  var monthPay;

  $('.results').addClass('hidden');


  // Calculate Monthly Payment
  calcButton.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    monthPay = (monthlyInterestRate * amount) / [1 - Math.pow((1 + monthlyInterestRate), -duration)];
    $('.durationValue').text(duration);
    $('.monthlyPayment').text(Math.round(monthPay));
    $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
  });

  resetButton.click(function() {
    $(form).reset();
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="loan-calc">
  <form id="calculator">
    <input type="text" name="loanAmount" id="loanAmount" placeholder="Loan Amount"><br>
    <label>Choose your payment duration:</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="duration" value="12" class="duration"> 12 Months<br>
    <input type="radio" name="duration" value="18" class="duration"> 18 Months<br>
    <input type="radio" name="duration" value="24" class="duration"> 24 Months <br>
    <button class="calculate">Calculate</button>
    <!--            <button class="rest">Reset</button>-->
  </form>
  <p class="results">You chose a duration of <span class="durationValue"></span> months and your monthly payment is $<span class="monthlyPayment"></span> at a 12% yearly interest rate.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Problem 1 was to not make a snippet so we can see it in action. I made one for you. problem 2 is you only get the values when the page loads. Put the `var amount = $('#loanAmount').val();` etc inside the calculation function. You need them to be fetched for every click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you take the values of duration and amount on pageload (document ready). if you update the values by filling them in, the variables won't get updated.

move `var amount = $('#loanAmount').val();` and `var duration = $('input[name=duration]:checked').val();` into the 'onClick' handler so that the amount and duration get updated once you click.

Comment: There's no need to move it by setting another handler - it's more efficient to get values only when whole calculation is triggered

Comment: ... aka "into the onclick handler"

Comment: @pkolawa, who is talking about *another* click handler??

Comment: @DoXicK you by saying: use onClick which sounds like changing value of duration variable by onClick attribute - there's no need to store and update this variable from starting from pageload

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the vars inside the function that uses them

PS: In a form an `input type="reset" />` will reset the form without needing script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.results').addClass('hidden');
  var yearlyInterestRate = .12;
  var monthlyInterestRate = yearlyInterestRate / 12;
  var twelveMon = 12;
  var eighteenMon = 18;
  var twentyFourMon = 24;


  // Calculate Monthly Payment
  $('.calculate').on("click", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var amount = $('#loanAmount').val();
    var duration = $('input[name=duration]:checked').val();
    var monthPay = (monthlyInterestRate * amount) / [1 - Math.pow((1 + monthlyInterestRate), -duration)];
    $('.durationValue').text(duration);
    $('.monthlyPayment').text(Math.round(monthPay));
    $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
  });

  $('.reset').on("click", function() {
    $(form).reset();
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="loan-calc">
  <form id="calculator">
    <input type="text" name="loanAmount" id="loanAmount" placeholder="Loan Amount"><br>
    <label>Choose your payment duration:</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="duration" value="12" class="duration"> 12 Months<br>
    <input type="radio" name="duration" value="18" class="duration"> 18 Months<br>
    <input type="radio" name="duration" value="24" class="duration"> 24 Months <br>
    <button class="calculate">Calculate</button>
    <!--            <button class="rest">Reset</button>-->
  </form>
  <p class="results">You chose a duration of <span class="durationValue"></span> months and your monthly payment is $<span class="monthlyPayment"></span> at a 12% yearly interest rate.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting values on `document.ready()` - so it's even before any of examples in radio will be clicked. Move getting you values into the `.click()` function

And it's even more efficient to switch from deprecated `.click()` method to `.on('click', function(){})` just in case you'll expand your form in the future

Comment: Click is not deprecated. It is a  shorthand for on.("click" - https://api.jquery.com/click/